# asp.net jQuery json autocomplete data doesn't seem to be correct

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am using jQuery to call a web service method to perform autocomplete but the data in the autocomplete/suggestion drop down of the textbox isn't the same as when I run the query directly.

This is the jQuery that's inside the `document.ready` function:

```
$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../cspm/s3.asmx/SearchSrn1',
                data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },

        minLength: 2
    });
```

This is the code from the web service method:

```
<WebMethod(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function SearchSrn1(ByVal prefixText As String) As String()

    Dim results As New List(Of String)()

    Dim searchText As String() = prefixText.Split(New Char() {" "c})

    sql = New StringBuilder()
    sql.Append("select rownum,b.* from ")
    sql.Append("(select distinct a.* from imsi_keyword_lookup_b a ")
    sql.Append("where keyword like upper('%" + searchText(0).ToUpper() + "%') ")

    For i As Integer = 1 To searchText.Length - 1
        If searchText(i) <> "" Then
            sql.Append("and keyword like '%" + searchText(i).ToUpper() + "%' ")
        End If
    Next

    sql.Append("order by rank desc) b ")
    sql.Append("where rownum <= 5 ")

    Using rdr As System.Data.IDataReader = db.ExecuteDataReader(sql.ToString())
        Dim counter As Integer
        While rdr.Read
            If (counter = 5) Then Exit While
            results.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", rdr("keyword"), rdr("keyword")))
            counter += 1
        End While
    End Using

    Return results.ToArray()


End Function
```

When I type gif I am returned 5 results as I should but they all say GIF in the dropdown portion of the textbox. When I run the query with GIF as the keyword I get: `GIF-Q, GIF-160, GIF-Q180, GIF-H180, GIF-Q160`.

Any ideas as to why I am not getting the correct data back?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I figured it out. I was using '-' as the split character and it was part of my result dataset. I changed it to use '|' and it's working now.